# Datepicker in Yii is storing data as yy MM d format

Tags: php, mysql, datepicker, yii

I have a form,in which the input field is like this

```
  <div class="row">
  <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'due_date'); ?>
  <?php 
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker',
      array(
            'attribute'=>'due_date',
            'model'=>$model,
            'options' => array(
                              'mode'=>'focus',
                              'dateFormat'=>'d MM, yy',
                              'showAnim' => 'slideDown',
                              ),
    'htmlOptions'=>array('size'=>30,'class'=>'date'),
          )
    );
  ?>
  <?php echo $form->error($model,'due_date'); ?>
  </div>
```

I have made save this form in model file.It is something like this

```
    protected function beforeSave()
  {
    $this->due_date=date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace(",", "", $this->due_date)));
    return TRUE;
  }
```

CJuiDatePicker is used to save the data from Date picker. It is showing the date in d mm yy format at the time of save but when I am going to update the form the date is showing in  yy MM d format.If I am changing the dateformat of beforeSave(), it is storing the date format in 0000-00-00 values.No other date values are storing. Can some one tell me where I am doing wrong? Any help and suggestions will be highly appriciable.

Comment: Did you try to dump the valie of $this->due_date after you change it, before it's saved? Log that out and check that the value is correct there.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are describing. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Jon, i think he's saying that the date field appears(populated) in YYYY-MM-DD format when he tries to update the model.

Comment: thanks @bool.dev for explain in short..

Comment: alright, try my solution below, btw! and follow up

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
protected function afterFind(){
    parent::afterFind();
    $this->due_date=date('d F, Y', strtotime(str_replace("-", "", $this->due_date)));       
}

protected function beforeSave(){
    if(parent::beforeSave()){
        $this->due_date=date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace(",", "", $this->due_date)));
        return TRUE;
    }
    else return false;
}
```

Add the above code to your model. And it should work.

Comment: Let me know if any clarification is required.

Comment: alright glad it worked, do remember to call `parent` methods, when you are overriding them, so that events are properly raised. also the afterFind helps us to reformat the data in the way we wanted, obviously you could have done that in the view itself, but i thought this is better.

Comment: ok..Can you tell me what is the role of parent here?Why it is called here?

Comment: the parent methods raise events `onAfterFind` in the parent `afterFind()` and `onBeforeSave` in the parent `beforeSave()`, read the documentation for the methods to know more, you should also check out the source of these parent methods in the yii documentation.

Comment: please note that i have changed the code, the function should be `protected` and not `public`. this is important.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with european dates, formatted like: 'dd/mm/yyyy', and this is what i use:

In model rules:

```
    public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('date','date','format'=>Yii::app()->locale->getDateFormat('medium')),
```

because 'medium' locale format fits my validation needs.

In the form I use:

```
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'date'); ?>
            <?php
            $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
                //'name'=>'date',
                'model'=>$model,
                'attribute'=>'date',
                'language'=>Yii::app()->language=='es' ? 'es' : null,
                'options'=>array(
                    'changeMonth'=>'true', 
                    'changeYear'=>'true',   
                    'yearRange' => '-99:+2',        
                    'showAnim'=>'fold', // 'show' (the default), 'slideDown', 'fadeIn', 'fold'
                    'showOn'=>'button', // 'focus', 'button', 'both'
                    'dateFormat'=>'dd/mm/yy',
                    'value'=>date('dd/mm/yy'),
                    'theme'=>'redmond',
                    'buttonText'=>Yii::t('ui','Select form calendar'), 
                    'buttonImage'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/calendar.gif', 
                    'buttonImageOnly'=>true,
                ),
                'htmlOptions'=>array(
                    'style'=>'vertical-align:top',
                    'class'=>'span2',
                ),  
            ));?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model,'date'); ?>
```

And the conversion back to MySQL format, for save, date comparisons...:

```
$date=strftime('%Y-%m-%d', strtotime(str_replace("/", "-", $this->date)));
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
public function beforeSave()
{
    $this->due_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime( $this->due_date));
    return parent::beforeSave();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'As_purchaseDate')->widget(
    'trntv\yii\datetime\DateTimeWidget',
    [
        'phpDatetimeFormat' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
        'clientOptions' => [
            'minDate' => new \yii\web\JsExpression('new Date("01-01-1996")'),
            'allowInputToggle' => false,
            'sideBySide' => true,
            'widgetPositioning' => [
               'horizontal' => 'auto',
               'vertical' => 'auto'

            ]
        ]
    ]);?>
```

Comment: Try to add some description of your code. Why your code work ?